# How to create a percentage + total for one variable in a matrix with rows and columns representing two categorical variables?

Tags: sum, tabs, pivot-table, stata, group

Let's say I have three variables:

1. female, dummy that takes 1 if female, 0 if otherwise
2. municipality, categorical variables of 10 categories (amsterdam, berlin, london, barcelona, copenhagen, oslo, stockholm, rome, vienna, lisbon)
3. industry, with 5 categories (manufacturing, government, services, transport, education)

I want to create a table with municipality as rows, industry as columns and then I want each cell to contain two values:

- % female for the particular combination of municipality and industry
- N total (both female and not female) for the particular combination of municipality and industry

Is it possible to make such a table in Stata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general code snippet that you should be able to adapt to your needs:

```
clear
set obs 10000

* Randomly create the data
set seed 123456
gen municipality = ceil(runiform()*10)
gen industry = ceil(runiform()*5)
gen female = (runiform()<.6)

*Calculate N and percentages (technically shares) by municipality and industry
collapse (mean) percent_female=female (count) N=female , by(municipality industry)

* Reshape so each row is a municipality
reshape wide percent_female N, i(municipality) j(industry)

* Export data to table
*ssc install dataout
local folder "path/to/folder"
dataout , excel save("`folder'/mytable.xlsx")
```